# R help files in plain text or man page format, greppable

Tags: r, grep, documentation, command-line-interface, tex

Can anyone point me to R help files in plain text or
[man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) format, greppable ?
By "help file" I mean either

- the file of 1-line command summaries that `??` looks in
- a tree of man pages, for `man`, `man -k` etc.

For example `??recycle` is funny, but not useful;
I'd much prefer `grep -iw recycle` or `man -k recycle` .

Sorry if this question is a duplicate --
it must be, but I haven't found it yet.

(`$R_HOME/doc/manual/*.html` and `*.pdf` must have been generated, from what text ?)

(Why grep ? Because it's *fast*, simple, and familiar -- for me,
who grew up when flipping between keyboard and mouse wasn't a problem: there was no mouse.)

---

Added: the .../*/man/*.Rd files in the src tar (thanks nicola) are latex.
[how-do-i-convert-latex-to-plain-text-ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530121/how-do-i-convert-latex-to-plain-text-ascii)
lists several possibilities;
unfortunately, `pandoc -f latex` quits early on these Rd files.

Comment: Just extract the `.tar.gz` package file and you'll find the `man` directory where the `.Rd` files are stored. Those files generate the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Use R itself, a pkg::func at a time.
R finds the help text somewhere and converts it to nearly-plain text somehow --
"where" and "how" are well-hidden but unimportant.

(In fact I had to use `Rscript` to get single help files:

```
# rhelp topic [package]: R help for one function  > stdout
# (sink(), help() geht nicht ?  in R 3.1.3  mac 10.8.3)

case $1 in
"" ) Rscript -e "help( package=${2-NULL} )" ;;
* )  Rscript -e "help( topic=\"$1\", package=${2-NULL} )"  # topic ":" "@" "[.data.frame"
esac  |

    # _\010U_\010s_\010a_\010g_\010e: -> Usage:
    # \010 is the single char ctl-H,  backspace
sed '
/^_/ s/_\010//g
'
```