# How to decode LaTex text from server to Android TextView?

Tags: android, latex, android-studio-2.3

Is there any way I can decode LaTex text coming from server and show in TextView of android?

LaTex contains some mathematical equations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530121/how-do-i-convert-latex-to-plain-text-ascii]

Comment: @Nilu I want to integrate into android studio so application can itself convert text then show to user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for my problem here.

Please go through mention link for more details.

[MathView in Android](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView)